# Caching Policy requirements ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core, authorization

In an ASP.NET Core MVC application, we use Policy requirements for Authorization that are defined using SQL Server database roles. We call `sp_helprolemember {roleName}` and then check if the User is a member to determine if they pass the requirement, example handler from the RequirementHandler:

```
// Get Role Members
IEnumerable<RoleMember> roleMembers = _roleMemberRepository.GetAllByRole(_roleName);
SecurityIdentifier userSid = new SecurityIdentifier(context.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.PrimarySid).SingleOrDefault().Value);

if (roleMembers.Any(rm => new SecurityIdentifier(rm.MemberSID, 0) == userSid))
{
    context.Succeed(requirement);
}
```

MemberSID is a `byte[]` array column from `sp_helprolemember`

This works, but my concern is querying the database each and every time we need to handle a requirement, which based on some code that's already written can be multiple times in one View.

Is it a better practice to cache this data somehow in memory to minimize database queries? I had the idea of using in-memory caching for each requirement handler to keep track of users that have previously been authorized and giving it a sliding window of a couple minutes before clearing, but I haven't worked with anything like that before and was wondering if there was a standard practice for doing something like this.

Comment: Does `GetAllByRole` return all members in the given rolename?

Comment: Yes, it simply calls the SQL Server system stored procedure sp_helprolemember with the provided role name.

Comment: Could it be thousand of rows depending on the number of the members assign to the rolename? Would you like to know the alternative approach which might require some modifications in your existing code?

Comment: It's unlikely the query result will ever be more than a dozen or so rows, but I'm always open to alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid database access on every request, we normally save an user's authorized rolename as role claims inside Principal. It basically encrypts those claims, and saves it inside a cookie.

```
// Login
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, user.Id.ToString()),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName)
};    
foreach (string roleName in authorizedRoleName)
{
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roleName));
}
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "local", "name", "role");
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

// Usage
if(context.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, _roleName))
    context.Succeed(requirement);
```

Comment: What is the lifecycle of that? Say if someone removes or adds a user to a role in the database.

Comment: If you want to validate the credentials, you will need to access database on every request. You can read more at [Reacting to back-end changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x#reacting-to-back-end-changes).

Comment: Is there a place where claims can be added when using Windows Authentication? I tried added Claims as above using ClaimsTransformer and setting roles there, then just checking for the claim in my RequirementHandler, but the code in my ClaimsTransformer ended up being executed more often than the RequirementHandler code so I didn't gain anything.

Comment: I have never tried mixing Windows Authentication with custom claims. However, if you don't mind asking user to login with their AD, I have [an open source project at GitHub](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit).